# postgresql: использование временной таблицы в запросе

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, where, temporary-table

есть запрос вида

```
SELECT 
    func1(field1)
FROM
   (
       SELECT
           func2(field2)
       FROM
           table1
       WHERE
           expression1
   ) AS r
```

подскажите, а можно ли делать выборку не из большой `table1`, а из таблицы, сформированной из записей `table1`, удовлетворяющих условию `expression1`?

я сейчас делаю это через создание временной таблицы:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp1 ON COMMIT DROP AS 
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM 
        table1
    WHERE
        expression1;

SELECT 
    func1(field1)
FROM
   (
       SELECT
           func2(field2)
       FROM
           tmp1
   ) AS r;
```

а можно ли временную таблицу вставить в сам запрос, чтоб не было 2 независимых команды, что-то на подобии:

```
SELECT
     (
        SELECT 
            func1(field1)
        FROM
           (
               SELECT
                   func2(field2)
               FROM
                   tmp1
           ) AS r
     )
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            * 
        FROM 
            table1
        WHERE
            expression1;
    ) AS tmp1;
```

P.S.

у меня есть запрос, который в качестве результата формирует json из нескольких РАЗНЫХ запросов к одной таблице с одинаковым условием, т.е. запрос работает с ОДИНАКОВЫМИ выбранными записями.

поэтому и подумалось, что чтоб не делать одинаковые выборки несколько раз из надо сделать только один раз заранее

и единственный вариант который нашел - создание временной таблицы, поэтому и подумалось, а нельзя ли всё включит в один sql запрос, а не в два

Comment: `WITH cte AS ()` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH

Comment: да, спасибо! то, что надо

Comment: Только помни - старые версии (по-моему, даже 14-я) безусловно материализуют CTE.